# Calling TransportClient's close() method in @Bean(destroyMethod = "close") instead of finally or try with resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm working on Spring and Elasticsearch integration and for that creating a TransportClient bean in a spring configuration class (annotated with @Configuration) which is further getting injected to service class, however for closing TransportCient bean, I'm doing it thru destroyMethod = "close" as shown below,

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public TransportClient client() { 
   client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(elasticsearchSettings);
   ...
   ...
   return client;
}
```

The bean instantiation and closing works perfectly fine, and this way it also helps me not instantiating bean multiple times which would have happen if I had to put above code in every method which may require to connect ES.

Can someone please tell me if above approach would be correct or there is any other better way to do so. Please let me know if any other details are needed.

Thanks in Advance..!